# The prop 'coordinate.longitude' is marked as required in 'MapMarker', but it's value is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, android-mapview, marker

While I'm working on my graduation project, I had some issues with expo/react native mapView, and it gives me this error, **So please can anyone help me ASAP.**

Here is my code if you want to check :

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, I18nManager, StyleSheet, } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';



I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
export default class MyMapView extends Component {

    //default state
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        
        
    }
    

    render() {
      
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <MapView
                    style={styles.map}
                    region={{
                        //we have muliple locations so we pass them here
                        latitude: this.props.latitude,longitude: this.props.longitude,
                        latitudeDelta:this.props.latitudeDelta ,
                        longitudeDelta: this.props.longitudeDelta, 
                    }} 
                >

                    <Marker coordinate={{   latitude: this.props.latitude,longitude: this.props.longitude}} />
                </MapView>
            </View>
        );


    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
    },
    map: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
    }
});
```

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add a condition to be sure that your props is not empty.
Try something like this:

```
export default class MyMapView extends Component {

...     

    render() {
      
        return (
           { this.props && <View style={styles.container}>
              <MapView
                    style={styles.map}
                    region={{
                        //we have muliple locations so we pass them here
                        latitude: this.props.latitude,longitude: this.props.longitude,
                        latitudeDelta:this.props.latitudeDelta ,
                        longitudeDelta: this.props.longitudeDelta, 
                    }} 
                >

                    <Marker coordinate={{   latitude: this.props.latitude,longitude: this.props.longitude}} />
                </MapView>
            </View>
  }
           );


    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error due to the dot in (this.props)

Comment: What is the error that it gives to you ?